# How to support content negotiation with Actix Web?

Tags: rust, actix-web, content-negotiation

My Rust Actix Web application provides multiple routes to the same resource with different content types. The example below works fine with `curl localhost:8080/index -H "Accept:text/html` but not in the browser (tested with Firefox developer edition), because that sends `Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8`.

Is there a way to comfortably handle real-world accept headers such as those, including wildcards and priority scores with the "q" attribute, or do I have to implement this logic myself?

```rust
use actix_web::{guard, web, App, HttpResponse, HttpServer};                   

#[actix_web::main]
async fn main() -> std::io::Result<()> {
    HttpServer::new(|| {
        App::new().service(
            web::resource("/index")
                .route(
                    web::get()  
                        .guard(guard::Header("Accept", "text/html"))
                        .to(|| async {
                            HttpResponse::Ok()
                                .content_type("text/html")
                                .body("<html><body>hello html</body></html>")
                        }),                                            
                )
                .route(
                    web::get()
                        .guard(guard::Header("Accept", "text/plain"))
                        .to(|| async {
                            HttpResponse::Ok()
                                .content_type("text/plain")
                                .body("hello text")
                        }),
                ),
        )
    })
    .bind(("127.0.0.1", 8080))?
    .run()
    .await
}
```

To clarify the expected behaviour:

- the application defines multiple routes with contents C1...Cn with content types T1...Tn in order of preference
- the client (e.g. web browser) sends a get request
- if there is no accept header in the get request, return C1 with content type T1
- if there is an accept header but there is no matching content type including wildcards, return an error response
- if there are multiple matching content types, return the one with the highest q score, assume 1 if not given
- if there are multiple matching content types with the same highest q score, return the one with the lowest index (highest preference by the application)

I could implement this logic myself but given that this seems to be a common case, I was wondering if there is some established method in place that already handles this (or a similar) use case with Actix Web.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you have to write your own guard, but you don't have to parse the header yourself. https://docs.rs/actix-web/latest/actix_web/guard/struct.GuardContext.html#method.header

```rust
// from https://docs.rs/actix-web/latest/actix_web/guard/struct.GuardContext.html#method.header
use actix_web::{guard::fn_guard, http::header};

let image_accept_guard = fn_guard(|ctx| {
    match ctx.header::<header::Accept>() {
        Some(hdr) => hdr.preference() == "image/*",
        None => false,
    }
});
```